# Apex Trigger: SOQL query excluding first ever record with filter

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, bulkification

I have written following trigger that will tick **Duplicate** checkbox if a registration record with same client and event already exist.

It works but it also ticks **Duplicate** checkbox if I edit first ever record for the client-event combination.

How can I modify the Trigger so it doesn't tick **Duplicate** checkbox for the oldest(first) record with client-event combination?

```
trigger Duplicate_Registration_BIBU on Registration__c (before insert, before update) {
    if(Duplicate_Registration_BIBU.firstRun)
    {
        // Set of all registration IDs in the trigger
        Set <Id> regoIds = new Set <Id> ();
        // Set of all client IDs in the trigger
        Set <Id> clientIds = new Set <Id> ();
        // Set of all event IDs in the trigger
        Set <Id> eventIds = new Set <Id> ();
        // Map of composite key (Client__c + Event__c) and matching Registration in the system (existing)
        Map <String, Registration__c> ECR = new Map <String, Registration__c> (); 

        // Find all the targeted event and client IDs
        for (Registration__c r : Trigger.new)
        {
            regoIds.add(r.Id);
            clientIds.add(r.Client__c);
            eventIds.add(r.Event__c);
        }

        // Query the existing registrations and populate the map (1 query)
        for(Registration__c existingR : [SELECT Id, Client__c, Event__c FROM Registration__c WHERE Client__c IN :clientIds AND Event__c IN :eventIds AND Id NOT IN :regoIds])
        {
            ECR.put('' + existingR.Client__c + existingR.Event__c, existingR);
        }

        // Loop again through the Registrations in the trigger
        for (Registration__c r : Trigger.new)
        {
            // For the ones that there are no matching Regisrations based on the composite key, set Duplicate__c True
            if (ECR.get('' + r.Client__c + r.Event__c) == NULL)
            {
                // set Duplicate__c False
                r.Duplicate__c = False;
            } else {
                // set Duplicate__c True
                r.Duplicate__c = True;
            }
        }
        Duplicate_Registration_BIBU.firstRun = False;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use containsKey instead of checking for null.

```
if (!ECR.containsKey('' + r.Client__c + r.Event__c))
        {
            // set Duplicate__c False
            r.Duplicate__c = False;
        } else {
            // set Duplicate__c True
            r.Duplicate__c = True;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks j dow! I assume its just a suggestion and not an answer to my question?!

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code solves your issue.

What I have done is basically only mark the `Duplicate__c` field as checked if there is already an existing `Registration__c` record in the DB, excluding the trigger records.

```
trigger Duplicate_Registration_BIBU on Registration__c (before insert, before update) {
    if(Duplicate_Registration_BIBU.firstRun) {
        Set <Id> triggerRegistrationIds = new Set <Id>();
        Set <Id> clientIds = new Set <Id>();
        Set <Id> eventIds = new Set <Id>();
        Map <String, Registration__c> registrationsByClientEventKey = new Map <String, Registration__c>(); // Map of composite key (Client__c + Event__c) and matching Registration in the system (existing)

        for (Registration__c r : Trigger.new) {
            triggerRegistrationIds.add(r.Id);
            clientIds.add(r.Client__c);
            eventIds.add(r.Event__c);
        }

        for(Registration__c existingRegistration : [SELECT Id, Client__c, Event__c FROM Registration__c WHERE Client__c IN :clientIds AND Event__c IN :eventIds AND Id NOT IN :triggerRegistrationIds]) {
            registrationsByClientEventKey.put(existingR.Client__c + existingR.Event__c, existingRegistration);
        }

        for (Registration__c triggerRegistration : Trigger.new){
            if (registrationsByClientEventKey.containsKey(triggerRegistration.Client__c + triggerRegistration.Event__c)){
                triggerRegistration.Duplicate__c = True;
            }
        }

        Duplicate_Registration_BIBU.firstRun = False;
    }
}
```

I have also taken the liberty to edit your variables and delete your comments following some coding and Apex best practices (naming, indentation, etc.). I know this isn't a code review, but I thought you might find it useful.

Also, out of scope aswell, I'd like to point out that you should try and use a [trigger framework](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices) instead of creating a trigger for each functionality. Feel free to open another question regarding this topic or read older questions since you'll find multiple good solutions. It will help you avoid tricky workaround like the `Duplicate_Registration_BIBU.firstRun` you coded.

Comment: My code also exclude triggering records. Your code works exactly like my code.  It still tick Duplicate for the first ever record. 

Really appreciate your suggestion of using framework and improving my code with best practices.

Comment: @Neerav is the field default to false? I'll double check it later, but it made sense yesterday when I posted it.

Comment: yes, Default is False.